# uitableviewcontroler con titleForHeaderInsection

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitableviewcell

Hola mi problema es el siguiente Tengo varias celdas creadas, con sus respectivos títulos cada uno, pero cuando intento agregar más iten a cada celda obtengo  error  , o no presenta el valor en la celda este es un ejemplo del app [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la pregunta es donde esta ejemplo area de calculo que se encuentra la celda a como puedo agregar ota celda dentro de esa area sin afectar las otras , estoy usando el siente codigo

```
/
//  ViewControllerGeometry.swift
//  calculos2
//
//  Created by Liantony Pozo on 7/19/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Liantony Pozo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewControllerGeometry: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

     var tableArray : [Problems] = []
     var tableArrayGeometryProblem : [Problemp] = []
     var tableArrayProblemsSecond : [ProblemsSecond] = []


     var segueIdentifiers = ["prueba" , "B", "C"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let geometryproblem = Problems (name : "a")
        tableArray.append(geometryproblem)



        let geometryProblemSecond = ProblemsSecond(nameSecond: "b")
        tableArrayProblemsSecond.append(geometryProblemSecond)

        let perimeterProblem = Problemp(nameGeometryProblem: "c")
        tableArrayGeometryProblem.append(perimeterProblem)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {


        case 0:

            return tableArray.count

        case 1 :

            return tableArrayProblemsSecond.count

        case 2:
            return tableArrayGeometryProblem.count



        default:
           return 0
        }

    //return tableArrayGeometryProblem.count


}




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellGeometryproblem")! as  UITableViewCell


        let geometryproblem = tableArray [indexPath.row]
        let perimeterProblemCalculation = tableArrayGeometryProblem [indexPath.row]
        let geometryProblemSecond = tableArrayProblemsSecond [indexPath.row]




        switch indexPath.section {



        case 0 :
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = geometryproblem.name
            }
        case 1 :


            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = geometryProblemSecond.nameSecond

            }


        case 2 :

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = perimeterProblemCalculation.nameGeometryProblem

            }

        default:
            break

            }
        return cell


        }
      /*  switch indexPath.section {

     case 0:
            cell.textLabel?.text = geometryproblem.name
        case 1 :
            cell.textLabel?.text = perimeterProblemCalculation.nameGeometryProblem



        default:
            return cell
        }



    return cell
    }*/





        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row + indexPath.section], sender: self)




            }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var title = ""


        switch section {
        case 0:
            title = "Area calculation "
        case 1 :

            title = "Perimeter calculation "

        case 2 :

            title = "Sen theorem "


        case 3 :

            title = "Inside angles of the triangle "



        default:
            break
        }
        return title
    }

}
```

aveces solo me presenta un solo valor en la celda no me presenta el otro o me da error en el codigo si algien me pudiera orientar en ese problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que te pasa es que si por ejemplo tuvieras esto:

```
let geometryproblem = Problems (name : "a")
tableArray.append(geometryproblem)
let geometryproblem2 = Problems (name : "z")
tableArray.append(geometryproblem2)
```

En la tabla solo te aparecería el Problems("a").
Si es eso, es porque cuando vas a pintar la celda te aseguras de que sea la row 0, y entonces pintas la tabla, si no es la 0 no haces nada. El el cellForRowAtIndex tienes esto:

```
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0 :
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = geometryproblem.name
        }
    case 1 :
    ......
```

Le estas diciendo que para la sección 0, si es la primera celda que se pinte, en caso contrario que no haga nada. Deberia quitar ese if. Ademas no seria necesario que obtuvieras el modelo de todos los datos, obtenlo solo del que necesites.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellGeometryproblem")! as  UITableViewCell

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0 :
        let geometryproblem = tableArray [indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = geometryproblem.name
    case 1 :
        let geometryProblemSecond = tableArrayProblemsSecond [indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = geometryProblemSecond.nameSecond
    case 2 :
        let perimeterProblemCalculation = tableArrayGeometryProblem [indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = perimeterProblemCalculation.nameGeometryProblem
    default:
        break
        }
    return cell
    }
```

En la ultima sección no aparece nada porque tienes un break en el cellForRowAtIndex.

Si este no es tu problema, entonces no he entendido lo que te sucede

Comment: de esa forma funciona presenta en pantalla pero con los segues no siguen el orden de cambio

Comment: No se xq sumas el indexPath.section y el indexPath.row. Imagina la primera seccion, que tengas 10 celdas. Si pulsas la ultima tendría que ir al segue apuntado por segueIdentifiers[0], pero le dices que vaya al segueIdentifiers[10]. Lo lógico es que se pare por indice fuera de rango. Así pues tienes que hacer el performsegue solo al segueIdentifiers[ indexPath.section]

Comment: lo puse [indexPath.row + indexPath.section] porque si elimino el indexpah.row en la primera sección todas las celdas se dirigen al primer segué

Comment: claro, y a cual deberían ir?

Comment: cada celda a un view diferente , funciona perfecto en la primera sección ejemplo la celda a se dirige al segué a , la z a la z  , en la otra sección debería ser c a la c pero se dirige a la z igual

Comment: pero vas a tener solo una celda por sección? entonces has de poner el indexPath.section y ya esta

Comment: voy a tener 2 casos por sección ya intente poniendo indexpah.section y me sale el mismo error

Comment: Ejemplo en la primera sección se encuentra A ( como está en la imagen ) pero cuando agregó ejemplo z en esa sección  . Entonces z y b quedan pasando al mismo segué

Comment: pues entonces deberías tener un switch con indexPath.section, para el case 0 hacer un if indexPath.row == 0 hacer tal, else hacer cual y asi para cada opción del switch

Comment: me funcionó de  esa forma